# Showing matching lines from a search using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of code that searches the current information shown on the page from a input source, which is an XML loaded in. This then shows how many times the word has been found, it should then display the lines where the word was found although currently it is showing all the lines. The code is

```
function searchResults(query) {
    var temp = "\\b" + query + "\\b";
    var regex_query = new RegExp(temp, "gi");
    var currentLine;
    var num_matching_lines = 0;
    $("#mainOutput").empty();
    $("LINE", g_playDOM).each(
            function() {
                currentLine = $(this).text();
                matchesLine = currentLine.replace(regex_query,
                        '<span class="query_match">' + query + '</span>');

                if (currentLine.search(regex_query) > 0)
                    num_matching_lines++;
                $("#mainOutput").append("<p>" + matchesLine + "</p>");
            });
    $("#sideInfo").append(
            "<p>Found " + query + " in " + num_matching_lines + " lines</p>");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    loadPlay();

    $("#term_search").focus(function(event) {
        $(this).val("");
    });

    $("#term_search").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
            searchResults($("#term_search").val());
    });

    $('#term-search-btn').click(function() {
        searchResults($("#term_search").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Currently the number of lines the word is on is being shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a line of code to be executed within a conditional, then you need to place curly braces around it. Otherwise, only the *very next action item* will be executed. In your case, increase the count of the number of lines that match.

Your subsequent action item, appending the found line into the DOM is executed on every branch because the `if` statement has already done its job. Offending lines below:

```
if ( currentLine.search(regex_query) > 0 ) num_matching_lines++;
    $("#mainOutput").append("<p>" + matchesLine + "</p>");
```

Fixed:

```
if ( currentLine.search(regex_query) > 0 ) {
    num_matching_lines++;
    $("#mainOutput").append("<p>" + matchesLine + "</p>");
}
```

Comment: I have changes this and it is still showing all lines instead of "matchesLine" any idea why this would be happening or what i could do to fix this?

Comment: You should use your browser's Development tool to break through and find out what text is coming through. Since you haven't uploaded a jsfiddle.net displaying the problem, I can't do it for you. But it probably has something to do with what `replace()` returns, that you're appending `matchesLine` instead of `currentline` or need to find `.val()` instead of `.text()` but it's hard to say since you haven't shown your HTML.